# intellisence work in one file and in the other file not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, intellisense

Hi I have really annoying problem I am writing MVC 4 application and I have two files in the same project in one file intellisence work great: (added picture)
[image]

and in the second file intellisence not work at all!
[image]

someone know what the problem?

Comment: I have had Intellisense failing on me occasionally. On all of those occasions, I have restarted Visual Studio and got it to work again. Have you tried restarting?

Comment: yes I restarted visual studio and I still have the same problem...